# iOS 11.1 keyboard bug

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios11

For my existing iOS-projects, I noticed a keyboard bug when I run the app's on an iOS 11.1 simulator / real device: The bar above the keyboard is flipping high and down, after I switched from one textfield to another. For testing purposes, I created a new iOS project from scratch and the bug occurs again. Does anybody have the same issue (and maybe a solution)?

Under the link https://ufile.io/en8eg there is a demonstration video.

Greetings!

Comment: https://ufile.io/ is currently not reachable from my country.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off the predictive text, I think that's what you were referring to when you said "the bar above the keyboard".

Try this in the viewDidLoad:

```
textField.autocorrectionType = .no // Swift 4
```